# Implement signature verification on the runner side, via config file /etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-ce

I have installed Gitlab, and generate the keys, and try to push new things and commit with sign and everything is working properly as it should. However, I want to implement signature verification on the gitlab-runner/config.toml  file. Can you give me a correct .gitlab-ci.yml code as well as a correct  config.toml file code. My problem is taht I am writing an incorrect .yml and .toml file which are important to implement the Signature Verification.  Thank you for your time

I am expecting a good quality config.toml & .gitlab-ci.yml files

Comment: I don't really understand what you're trying to do or what your config.toml or .gitlab -ci.yml have to do with GPG signing. But have you considered just using the "reject unsigned commits" [push rule](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/repository/push_rules.html)?